# How could I determine the data from clicking a link?

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie in php and working on something something and I can't figure out how will it work. I have a query like this which will display specific rows from the database:

```
<?php 
include ('test/tru/conek.php');

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post_jobs WHERE job_category='Administration'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr >
  <th style="font-weight:normal"><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php $name=$row['company_name']; echo $name ; ?>" readonly="readonly" /></th>

  <th style="font-weight:normal"><a href="#" onclick="ss()" name="res"><?php echo $row['job_responsibilities']; ?></a></th>

  <th style="font-weight:normal" id="industry"><?php echo $row['industry']; ?></th>

  <th style="font-weight:normal" id="date"><?php echo $row['date']; ?></th>

  <th style="font-weight:normal" id="loc"><?php echo $row['location']; ?></th>
</tr>

</table>

<?php } ?>
```

My question is, how could I display or determine the information on a specific row from clicking the link and then displaying it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do?  Are you saying that you want display information in the field when someone clicks that "res" link?  If so, that is done client side and has little to do with PHP, unless you are calling a script with AJAX.

Comment: What do you want to happen when they click the link? Go to a new page? Display some sort of popup?

Comment: When you click the res link the current data in the page will disappear and then display data just about the link which was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want differentiate between the rows after printing them onto screen. The most common way of doing this is by using an id number for each row. You add an 'id' row which is auto incrementing and primary into your mysql table. You would then add it to the link in your html:

```
<th style="font-weight:normal">
  <a href="#" onclick="ss(<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>)" name="res">
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['job_responsibilities'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
  </a>
</th>
```

You would then do something with that id number in Javascript in your ss() function. If you infact don't want to use Javascript at all, then you should write your link tag as:

```
<th style="font-weight:normal">
  <a href="somewhere.php?id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" name="res">
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['job_responsibilities'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
  </a>
</th>
```

I think that's what you're looking for.

**Edit:** How silly of me, I also forgot to mention that you should never print user-supplied data in your html without first escaping it. This is to prevent [Cross Site Scripting (XSS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) which is a common yet very serious vulnerability in web pages. I've edited my code accordingly. You should replace the 'UTF-8' with the correct encoding of your data. This is the reason you should also explicitly state the encoding: http://shiflett.org/blog/2007/may/character-encoding-and-xss

Comment: You're welcome. If you believe that it answered your question, then please make sure you accept the answer.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? What have you tried? What was the output? Any errors?

Comment: You should list all the different methods you've tried, including what you expected the output to be, and what it actually was. It's difficult to help you without such information.